# Can I explain lift in this way?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, lift

[image]

** As shown above, Suppose the wing moves horizontally.**

The red arrow is the direction of air movement at the top of the wing. This direction is not perpendicular to the normal line at the top of the wing and is greater than 90 degrees. Therefore, the air tends to leave the wing along the normal line, so the air pressure at the top of the wing decreases.

The blue arrow is the movement direction of the air at the bottom of the wing, which is not perpendicular to the normal at the bottom of the wing and is less than 90 degrees. Therefore, the air tends to approach the wing along the normal, so the air pressure at the bottom of the wing increases.

The air pressure at the top of the wing decreases, and the air pressure at the bottom of the wing increases. There is a pressure difference, which leads to the generation of lift.

Comment: Pressure is force/surface. Is your explanation really different from the common one?

Comment: @Alchimista I mean, there's a trend towards normal motion.

Comment: You even said "when the air moves, red arrow". Else the force is that described by P.Assuming all the other forces are properly considered I see your explanation as the standard one, just more complicated. Yes, if you could count the impact of air molecules to each side, it would be unbalanced and the difference grow with the red arrow . But somehow you are refusing to use P. This is what it seems to me, of course. Otherwise I would have answered saying NO.

Comment: @Alchimista To avoid misunderstanding, I have revised my questions.

Comment: Then yes. Bullets or not, which I didn't introduce in this discussion, it seems an explanation. And the standard one. Indeed you do not refer to something "new" anymore. It can be formulated with the time that air takes to clean the wing at the two sides, but essentially this is lift. At least I think so.

Comment: @Alchimista Air tends to move in the normal direction, which determines lift.

Comment: No, no as formulated. Of course lift is an unbalance of the momentum imparted on the two sides, or the force acting on them > pressure. You don't say something wrong just the way is convoluted. Though meantime the Q body is totally different.

Comment: Yes somehow one side get clean of an amount of air faster than the other. So the overall bulleting on the sides is unbalanced and the wing experiences a net force. But P and Flow are more adequate to treat fluids. But it seems that a microscopical interpretation as it is now is correct.

Comment: @Alchimista The direction of the speed and the angle of the surface of the wing determine whether the pressure is reduced or increased.

Answer (score -1):

This wouldn't be a correct way of describing lift.

We cannot assume individual particles of air as air is actually a continuum. If we consider individual particles,they would behave more like bullets ricocheting of surfaces,which is not what happens.

The real reason is to do with circulation which speeds up flow on one side and slows it down on the other and most importantly the kutta condition.

Fundamentals of Aerodynamics by John D Anderson gives a complete explaination of this.

Comment: This answer is too drastic. Gas are statistically described, and how and many bullets impact on the two sides is what leads ultimately to lift. Just this can be done using fluids dynamics and using, at least not explicitly, a macroscopic view and P tout court.I tried to convey this to the OP, too. But it could be his/her way to elaborate a problem. I would strongly discourage this for teaching, for instance.

Comment: So as far as the bullet theory is concerned,we actually can't use it as mentioned here:https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/wrong2.html. The top side of the airfoil contributes significantly to lift which is not considered in this theory.

Comment: That covers basic mistakes which are not in my assertion. I wanted to warn OP but this is obvious and I limited myself writing "assuming all other forces are properly considered...". The OP clearly should look at what happens at each side of the foil. But I took his/her sketch and text to be repeated for the bottom side and finally have the two forces compared.

Comment: Ahh okay. However as for the statistical model for gas,at least in fluid dynamics are whole assumption is that the fluid is a continuum,Doug McLean describes this very well in his book.

Comment: I've revised my question. You can look at it again.

Comment: @RishiChauhan I'm not using bullet theory. I'm talking about a point of continuous air that is not perpendicular to the normal direction of the wing.

Comment: @Alchimista I'm not using bullet theory. I'm talking about a point of continuous air that is not perpendicular to the normal direction of the wing.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood the question then.

Comment: @RishiChauhan Now do you think my explanation is correct?